# Class disappeared from model asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, model

I used this instruction to upgrade the Entity Framework from 5.0 to 6.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6

After it was done, some custom model classes are disappeared from the project. The Classes are still there in the project folder, but i can not add them to my project.

There are hunderts of this errors :

CS0246: The type or namespace name '***' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do you have some ideas how I can fix it ?

Comment: maybe those models ware excluded from your solution

Comment: Can you give some additional information on why you can't add them to your project? Is there an error message you're getting when attempting to add them?

Comment: After generating a EF 6.x code generation template (step 3.2 in the instruction), custom classes were deleted. And when I try to add this classes from folder it doesnt work.  Maybe the names of classes are allready exist in the ***.tt files. Is it possible to keep old custom model classes and upgrade the edmx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The are two types of code generation strategies in Entity Framework. I had **Legacy Object Context (edmx + designer.cs)**, but the instruction describes **T4**(**edmx +... .tt files**).

I found this link, it was very helpfull for me:https://dvoituron.com/2015/09/08/how-to-migrate-entityframework-5-to-entityframework-6-with-visual-studio-2015/

The solution for me was:

1. Set **Code Generation Strategy** to *Legacy Object Context*
2. Save the project(designer.cs will be written)
3. Copy my old custom model classes to the project folder
4. Restart the project
5. Add EF6 namespaces  (for example System.Data.**Entity.Core.** Objects.ObjectContext)
6. In my case i had to add `using System.Data.Entity;` in some classes (to recognize the EntityState)